# Насколько правильна реализация обработки onClick()

Tags: javascript, html

Начал изучать Javascript и структуры данных, пишу простую вещь.
Есть класс SinglyLinkedList - односвязный список. В нём есть метод pop(), который использует **this** для обращения к полям класса. Есть кнопка (id: **popSLL**), при нажатии на которую должен вызываться этот метод.
Т.к. в HTML прописывать JS-код плохая практика, я пишу в **main.js** следующее:

```
document.getElementById('popSLL').onclick = () => testList.pop();
```

Вопрос номер один: насколько хорош такой вариант? Насколько я понял, можно и через attachEvent прописать, и ещё пару способов есть. Или принципиальной разницы нет?

Стрелочная функция вместо обычной просто потому, что короче. А если просто присваивать метод (... = testList.pop;), то внутри метода **this** будет вообще в контексте HTML-элемента. В интернете подглядел, что такая проблема решается через замыкание. Насколько я понял, замыкание - это когда внутренняя функция становится доступной отдельно от внешней, при этом имеет и собственный scoup, и доступ к scoup внешней функции.
Поэтому в примере выше, судя по всему, совсем не замыкание, но всё работает. Однако всё равно спрашиваю на всякий случай, как правильно. )

Ну и вопрос номер два, уже отдельно: сейчас в корпоративной разработке вообще используют новую систему классов из ES6? Она намного удобнее прототипов, но, судя по MDN, не поддерживается IE (менее критично) и Оперой (намного более критично, мне кажется).

Comment: я бы не посоветовал задавать несколько разных вопросов в одном посте. Лучше на каждый вопрос завести свой пост.

Comment: 0)http://learn.javascript.ru/
1)`let El = document.getElementById('popSLL')`
2)El.onclick = foo; 
El.addEventListener('click',foo); 
El.addEventListener('click',bar); 
El.addEventListener('click',baz);
El.addEventListener('click',testList.pop.bind(testList));

Comment: @qwabra спасибо за bind, это прям то, что нужно. Не знал об этой функции.
learn.javascript.ru не использую, там устаревшие данные (в частности, до сих пор не знают про let и const), изучаю JS только на MDN

Comment: @FantaZ, ваше право. https://learn.javascript.ru/objects-more

Comment: @qwabra оформите свой комментарий как ответ